# Restriction to minimize vehicles in vehicle routing problem (VRP)

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I am currently reading a [paper about vehicle routing problem with time windows](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050916317252) and when formulating the main goals and restrictions the following is stated:

> Objective: **Minimize the number of vehicles** and the total travel distance.

> Assume N is a number of customers (1, 2, ..., n) that need to be serviced.
> $c_{ij}$ - the transportation cost from the customer i to j.

> $x_{ijk}$ - a variable taking value of 1 if the vehicle k is coming from the customer i to the customer j, and 0 if otherwise.

> Objective function: 
> $$Z = \sum_{k\in V}\sum_{i\in N}\sum_{j\in N} c_{ij}x_{ijk} \to min$$

One of the restrictions is the following:

> $$\sum_{j \in N}x_{0jk}=1,\forall k \in V$$

Doesn't the previous restriction imply that every vehicle will move from $0$ (depot) to a customer $j$?
If that was the case the number of vehicles wouldn't be minimized because it would force them all to be in use.

[Printscreen of the page here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzdlC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those constraints force every vehicle to be used.

One approach to minimize the number of vehicles is to start with $|V|=1$ and try to solve this problem for fixed $|V|$.  Increment $|V|$ until the problem is feasible.

Another approach is to introduce a binary variable $y_k$, replace the RHS of constraints (4) and (5) with $y_k$, and minimize $\sum_k y_k$.  You can also tighten constraint (3) by replacing the RHS with $q\cdot y_k$.